# Select path on java

Tags: java, netbeans, path

I have this code where i create a textfile, but as u can see, the path is hardcoded.

How can i set a code that the user selects the path and pass it to a string so i can put it into the code of saving the txt.

```
   public void saveSudoku() {

        try (


                PrintStream savedSudoku = new PrintStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\savedSudoku.txt"));) {
            for (int i = 0; i < usedMatrix.length; i++) {
                String sudokuNumber = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < usedMatrix[i].length; j++) {
                    sudokuNumber += " " + userSudoku[i][j] + " ";
                }
                savedSudoku.println(sudokuNumber);
            }
            savedSudoku.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (PrintStream levelAndHint = new PrintStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Daniel\\Desktop\\savedLevel.txt"));) {

            levelAndHint.println(labelLevel.getText() + " " + hintCounter);

            levelAndHint.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this a standalone java app?

Comment: please accept the answer if it resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options

- Set the value in the system environment variable

  `String path = System.getenv().get("custompath");`
- Save the path in a file which is in classpath and read it from the file
- If it is a standalone application, pass the path as the program arguments and capture it in main method

Answer (score 0):

You need to take path as a input using System.in, and the append it with with file name, as pass it as a argument to "new PrintStream"
      String s;

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a string");
  s = in.nextLine();
```

I hope it helps